# Got new credit card since booking DB ticket - how to provide ID on train?

Tags: trains, tickets, germany, paperwork

Since booking two tickets on Deutsche Bahn a couple months ago, I've gotten a new debit card with a new number. The DB website stresses that an ID (credit or debit card used for the purchase, or country ID from one of a few European countries) is required when the ticket is inspected, and that passports are not accepted.

Is there any way to switch the debit card number linked to the tickets? Otherwise, what are my options for identification when my ticket is checked? I'm an American citizen and I travel in two days.

Edit: I don't have my old card any more, since it was destroyed when I got my new card.

Comment: Perhaps your bank can issue a letter documenting old card number 1234 was replaced by new card 4321.  Otherwise be prepared to repurchase the ticket (I would imagine DB would refund the first charge in this case, same as airlines do).

Comment: That was my thought, too (the letter) - my bank opens in an hour so I'll call them up and ask.

Comment: You can edit your ticket in the Deutsche Bahn app. I am not sure if you can change the identification method though. If you bought a Flexipreis ticket, consider refunding and purchasing new tickets (after checking for a price increase).

Comment: @Calchas ID can't be edited but cancelling and rebooking a Flexpreis ticket would be free if done at least a day in advance (with the exception of reserved seats which would be cancelled but not refunded). However, if they have booked a (non-flexible) Sparpreis it can be rather expensive to do that exercise.

Comment: My understanding is that even a valid German ID card would not be accepted in this situation, it has to be the token associated with the ticket, even if you hold another type of ID that the DB would accept.

Comment: How similar is the old number to the new number? As I recall, they only care about the last four digits.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, the idea is to prevent using the PDF multiple times in the same train by multiple persons which their current system can't detect. Therefore they bind the ticket to the ID which (theoretically) only exists once. On the other hand, I had once three BahnCards with the same number and same expiry date issued by them...

Comment: @Calchas They also check the expiry date.

Comment: hey @davidvc.  it's a pain in the ass but you **quite simply have to immediately cancel your ticket and buy a new one**.  unfortunately that is the answer.  if very unfortunately this will cause you to miss on a bargain price, "you're screwed".

Comment: you can totally forget about the "letter" idea, no US bank will do that.  and it's highly likely that it would be not-accepted anyway!! just forget that idea.

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't know about US banks but my small local German bank puts a stamp and signature on everything that is factually correct (but sometimes takes a while to verify). That's the reason I use them as I often depend on that due to my unusual job situation. It's at least worth a try.

Comment: @JoeBlow Customer service can't change online tickets. Maybe they would cancel it for free but that's as much as they can do.

Comment: hi @neo - ah, thanks for that great info.  Sorry.......  Re the US banks, US banks can do nothing for anyone. There wouldn't be a procedure, there wouldn't be a button on the computer, to print out such a letter. I'm pretty sure.

Comment: I contacted my bank. They could have sent via US mail, in 3-5 days, a letter with my name and the last 4 of my old and new cards). Not much use, since I'll be traveling in 2 days, so I'll just try my luck with the conductor--but useful to know it was an option.

Comment: @neo That's why I use the word "token", it's not an ID at all in fact.

Comment: @Relaxed Ah yes, that's the better word for that. I try using that in the future, it's less confusing then the "official" one.

Comment: Have you contacted DB yet? It seems they are the best to advice you.

Comment: Why did you wait two months to deal with this just days before travelling?

Comment: Here's my experience (@neo @Relaxed) on all 3 of my train rides: no trouble explaining my situation and showing my passport, no need to repurchase tickets, and no "you should bring your credit card next time" or similar chastisement, but I suppose the latter could be a cultural artifact and doesn't mean I wasn't in technical violation of the ID policy.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The official website does not explain what to do in that scenario but the DB is very specific about it: You have to travel with the exact (credit or ID) card registered as a token when you booked the ticket, no exceptions. If the card expired, you are expected to present the old, expired card instead of the new one (or possibly both if you are travelling with a *Bahncard*). And it does not seem possible to change the token, even in person and with a very good reason, let alone online or from abroad.

Various forum posts (from people who had their credit card or ID card stolen or from DB support staff answering their questions) all confirm that you really are supposed to buy a new ticket, even if you can present another ID and some document from the police confirming the previous one was stolen. Rail guards do have the option to let it slip but apparently the recommended procedure is to charge you for the - current and therefore possibly higher - price of a ticket with a small surcharge (*Bordpreis*) and invite you to ask the customer service for a (partial) refund as a commercial gesture (*Kulanz*).

At this point, it therefore seems that you have the choice between two (bad) options:

- Cancel your ticket and buy another one. It will cost you some but at least you know exactly how much and you have some peace of mind during the trip.
- Try your luck, with the downside being that you might be forced to buy an even more expensive ticket in the train. Not necessarily the end of the world but rather frustrating. Seeking out a member of the crew as soon as possible rather than waiting for them to come to your seat can also be a good idea.

No matter what you do, you can also try your luck with the customer service afterward but that sounds like a lot of hassle for a foreign resident. In any case, they are unlikely to issue a full refund and typically give out vouchers (*Gutschein*) for future train travel rather than cold hard cash, which is probably not very useful for you.

Comment: I am also not sure how I would play it with the guard: Dumb foreigner or apologetic from the start? ;)

Comment: I would try speaking to the train staff as soon as boarding the train. That makes then more lenient. If they don't allow traveling with the ticket you should contact the support staff as you suggested. As far as I know the internal policy is to refund the price you paid on board the train (as soon as they can verify that the online ticket hasn't been used which takes a few weeks) minus a service charge. Not sure how they would refund to a foreign bank account though – likely you only get a voucher in that case.

Comment: @neo Yes, that's a good tip, forgot to mention that, thanks!

Comment: You would be in a bad situation if the trip contains a non-conducted regional train that is only spot-checked. In that case no conductor to ask and if getting into a spot-check they almost surely would see you as someone traveling without ticket.

Comment: **Seeking out a member of the crew as soon as possible** definitely good advice - go straight to a crew member immediately.

Comment: @neo To clarify, would the official policy be to refund the higher price of the ticket I paid on board the train, or the lower price of the ticket I'd prepurchased?

Comment: @davidvc The price you paid on board the train (minus 17,50€ or 7€ depending on a few factors). That's not the *official external* policy though and you are still at their mercy if they decide they don't feel like doing that today.

Comment: Say @Relaxed or anyone - on DB can you pay "with the app"?  Know what I mean?  On the TGV (or SBB - or something) you can identify yourself / get the ticket merly by **having the app** and it sort of knows your ticket.  I think (but I'm not sure) in that case you don't need the credit card - is that right?

Comment: @JoeBlow Even if using the app you still need to show some ID card which you entered while booking the ticket (e.g. credit card, some European ID cards, BahnCard)

Comment: hi @neo - ah fair enough then.  I really think the OP "is screwed", op should just buy a new ticket (cancelling the old) ASAP to minimize costs.  I'm still wondering how much the ticket is - if it is a short/cheap journey, it's not worth bothering: just see what happens onboard.

Comment: @neo I think your comments would make a pretty good answer if joined together. You provide useful information complementary to Relaxed's answer, since he describes the public-facing policy of DB and you describe the likely practical outcomes.

Comment: When you have photo copy of your old card, it might be ok to take this copy with you.

Comment: If not the official website, then what's your source for this information?

Comment: @NateEldredge Wrote this some time ago but I apparently read "various forum posts" at the time. Still, most of my answer is, in fact, clearly based on the official website, very much including the statement explaining that that website does not offer any solution. I don't think I wrote anywhere that it wasn't.

Answer (score 7):

I'll just stick this on as an answer for completeness (I previously posted it as a comment):

I took 3 DB rides without the card used to book the tickets with no problem. On all 3 of my train rides, there was no  trouble explaining my situation and showing my passport as ID, no need to repurchase tickets, and no "you should bring your credit card next time" or similar chastisement--but I suppose the latter could be a cultural artifact and doesn't mean I wasn't in technical violation of the ID policy.

Comment: Downvoter: if you explain your motivation, I can improve my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I just travel from Berlin to Prague last Thursday 09/15, I have lost ID Credit Card, I brought CC statement, a letter from American Express explaining the situation. I didn't use any of the documents.
I show the controller copy of the online tickets, he stamped the paper,  controller come 3 times during our trip without a problem.

Answer (score -2):

Download the DB app in your smartphone. Then use the ticket number to download the ticket into the DB app in your smart phone. It will become a *Handyticket* automatically. In that case all you show is your smartphone. I have done it several times.

Comment: You might want to replace "handy" by "mobile (phone)" or "cell (phone)" for all the non-Germans here ;-)

Comment: You still need the ID with a _Handyticket_. If you have both a Bahncard and used a credit or debit card as the ID they sometimes forget to check the ID after seeing the Bahncard, but it's still required. It just saves you from printing the ticket.